# Neo4j + nodejs: create node using javascript object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, neo4j-node

can't find whether this has been asked before or not, so bear with me.
I'm just starting to use Neo4j with a nodejs backend and the `neo4j-driver` driver. I wonder if it's possible to create a node with several properties without enumerating each one in the second argument to the `session.run` method.

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body; //{userId: "johnsmith", email: "john@smith.com", ...}
    session.run("CREATE (u:User {u}) RETURN u", user).then(function(response) {
        /*do stuff with newly created user*/
    }, function() {
        //handle error
    });
});
```

Currently, this yields the following error: `{code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing', message: 'Expected a parameter named u' }`, and if I change the above to:

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body; //{userId: "johnsmith", email: "john@smith.com", ...}
    session.run("CREATE (u:User {u}) RETURN u", {u: user}).then(function(response) {
        /*do stuff with newly created user*/
    }, function() {
        //handle error
    });
});
```

then the error reads: `{ code: 'Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError', message: 'Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof' }`.

This doesn't make much sense to me, given that [the refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1/cypher-refcard/) clearly states you can create a node using a map, like so: `CREATE (n {map})`; so I must obviously be getting something wrong. I hope I don't have to enumerate all a user's properties like so:

```
session.run("CREATE (u:User {userId: {u.userId}, email: {u.email}, ...}) RETURN u", {u: user}).then(/*...*/)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the user object have any nested objects?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Map could not be the value of the properties
- You can set properties using a parameter - http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/set/#set-set-all-properties-using-a-parameter
- So you need to check the input parameter and transform its properties if necessary.

---

For example:

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
    var params = {};
    //{userId: "johnsmith", email: "john@smith.com", ...}
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach( function(k) {
        var value = req.body[k];
        if (!isPrimitive(val)) value = JSON.stringify(value);
        params[k] = value;
    });

    session.run("CREATE (u:User) SET u = {user} RETURN u", {user: params})
        .then(function(response) {
            // do stuff with newly created user
        }, function() {
            // handle error
        });
});
```

Where `isPrimitive` an abstract function that checks whether a variable is a primitive.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, although I'm not very impressed since the ref card says nested properties are supported, but apparently they're not.

Comment: The ref card needs to be a bit more clear. Nested maps *are* supported for maps, in general. For instance, you can freely pass in JSON data as Cypher query parameters. However, nested maps are NOT supported for storing as property values. I have added a note to my alternate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j only supports storing *specific kinds* of data structures to a property. To quote from the [Cypher Refcard](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/):

> Neo4j properties can be strings, numbers, booleans or arrays thereof.

And, to be more exact, in order for an array (or "collection") to be stored as a property value, all its elements must be of the **same** primitive type.

The answer from @stdob-- provides one possible simple workaround to this (but it stringifies all arrays, even ones that can be stored without conversion).

NOTE: The refacrd needs to be a bit more clear. Nested **maps** *are* supported, in general. For instance, you can freely pass in JSON data as Cypher query parameters. However, maps containing nested maps are NOT supported for storing as *property values*.